# Why aren't there complex solutions to $\sin(x) = 0$?

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, proof-verification, complex-numbers

Suppose that the addition formula works for $\sin(a+bi) = 0$ where $a$ and $b$ are real. Then $\tan(a) = \tanh(b)$ for any real $b$ and $a$ are valid solutions to the given equation. There are many solutions to $a$ and $b$. But why do none of them yield $\sin(a+bi) = 0$?

Comment: I suggest you write out for us what you think the addition formula says, and how $\cos b\text{i}$ and $\sin b\text{i}$ are related to $\cosh b$ and $\sinh b$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $\sin(a+ib)=0$ does ***not*** imply that $\tan(a)=\tanh(b)$.  Rather, we see that

$$\sin(a+ib)=\sin(a)\cosh(b)+i\cos(a)\sinh(b) \tag 1$$

If $\sin(a+ib)=0$, then for $\cos(a)\ne 0$, $\tan(a)=-i\tanh(b)\ne \tanh(b)$.

And hence, $\sin(a+ib)=0$ when $a=n\pi$ and $b=0$.  These are the only solutions to $(1)$.

Comment: Why sin(ib)=i sinh(b)?

Comment: @J.P.C. It doesn't.  But $\sin(ib)=i\sinh(b)$.  Don't forget the $i$.

Comment: Yes but why is that?

Comment: ohh, silly mistake, I added an unecessary $i$ to say that $cos(ib) = icosh(b)4

Comment: @J.P.C. Using Euler's Formula, we have $$\sin(ib)=\frac{e^{i(ib)}-e^{-i(ib)}}{2i}=i\frac{e^{b}-e^{-b}}{2}=i\sinh(b)$$.

Comment: Aah I forgot the i with the sine in Euler's formula, thanks

Comment: @gebra All of us make careless errors.   So, don't worry about this one.  Just try to take away something positive from it.  -Mark

Comment: @J.P.C. Yes, it's understandable.